# calling method in super class using object of sub class how it work?

Tags: java, inheritance, casting, polymorphism, dynamic-binding

```
class SuperClass{  
  public void print(){
    System.out.println("I'm super class...");
  }  
  public void someMethod(){
    System.out.println("any thing");
  }
}  

class SubClass extends SuperClass{ 
  @Override
  public void print(){
    System.out.println("I'm sub class...");
  }  

  public static void main(String args[]){  
    SuperClass a=new SubClass(); 
    a.print();  
    a.someMethod();
  }  
}
```

`a.print()` known as dynamic binding and it's know which method to call in run time and choose method of SubClass because the object is SubClass it's true?

`a.someMethod()` how JVM deal with this method it's not in sub class and the object from sub class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a.print()` is an example of [method overriding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding) which is [runtime polymorphism](http://www.javatpoint.com/runtime-polymorphism-in-java). That is, at runtime it decides whether to call the subclass method or the super class method (here your `SubClass` method is called as it is overridden and matches the parameter signature).

In case of `someMethod()` call, you have not defined it in your SubClass. That means, your `SubClass` automatically got a `someMethod()` when you inherited it from `Superclass` as it is `public`. Putting it in simple words, SubClass also has the definition of `someMethod()`. Thats how JVM got to know which method to call.

Also in `SuperClass a`, the variable 'a' will be stored in stack whereas the reference will be stored in heap. You have constructed the reference using `SubClass`'s constructor. Meaning the variable 'a' in stack refers to a '`SubClass`' object in heap. That is why 'a' is able to call `someMethod`

Comment: why we can't call method from SubClass although we create object from the SubClass and hold its address in SuperClass variable??

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
SuperClass a = new SubClass();
```

You're saying that you want to make an instance of `SubClass`, where you only want methods declared in `SuperClass` to be visible. If you had declared any new methods in `SubClass`, they would not be visible.

The object will still be using the `SubClass` implementations when it can (i.e. when you override them). Methods which haven't been overridden will use the implementation that was inherited.

Answer (score 0):

"calling method in super class using object of sub class" is one of the scenario of [Polymorphism in Java](http://www.tutorialkart.com/java/polymorphism-in-java/).

If the sub-class implements a method with same definition as that of super-class, calling the method with the object of sub-class is going to override the method of super-class with the method of sub-class.

Hence, if you want to call the method of super class with the object of sub-class, don't override the method.

```
SuperClass a=new SubClass();
```

This definition makes "a" capable to make a reference to type SuperClass or any sub-class that extend the SuperClass. As object "a" is created from SubClass, by definition, the object can access the methods of the SubClass and SuperClass. This explaination should address both of your questions.

Refer to the java documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html).